# How to reverse algorithm of id => key conversion?

Tags: algorithm, security, reverse

I have some set of pairs (id,key).

Set 1:

```
id=12877074 key=2ac90cf4
id=12877104 key=7d2ab9ab
id=12877134 key=11b2ec50
id=12877201 key=c428eb88
id=12890200 key=d8ad8b8c
id=12901142 key=f04896ba
id=12913608 key=934d4ad5
```

Set 2:

```
id=1168056109 key=L949f50be7a
id=1243780701 key=L254ecc879b
id=1247980634 key=M788bd17c10
id=1300610428 key=M5fa760c4a0
id=1317428974 key=Md2e645bac9
```

Is it possible to detemine how can I obtain key from id?

Comment: Trial and error I guess... if you don't have any information about the key.

Comment: Obviously the id is a string of digits `0-9` that represents a number in decimal, and the key is a string of hexadecimal digits `0-9,a-f` that represent a number in hexadecimal, possibly preceded by the capital letter `L` or `M` in the second set. The fact that these numbers are represented in hexadecimal suggests one of the popular hash functions MD5, SHA-1, or similar, is used, so you could try to test all the most popular hash functions and see if you get a match.

Comment: Also, any information as to where these pairs (id, key) come from would be tremendously helpful.

Comment: If you had any reason to believe that the numbers represented by the keys were obtained from the numbers represented by the ids using an affine function, or perhaps a polynomial function, you could use linear regression to find the best-fitting coefficients. Or simply solve the system of equations to find an exact solution if there is one. But unless you have more information about where these pairs (id, key) come from, I would find that very unlikely.